# VSTO Outlook: Change border and header background color of custom task pane

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, customtaskpane

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in. I have put a custom task pane at the top. This custom task pane contains an WPF user control.Now I am trying to change the background color of the header (title bar) and borders of the custom task pane (I am not referring to the background of the WPF user control). Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. The Office extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. You may try using the Windows API functions for that, at lease you can inject your own form. Such forms MS calls Adjucent Outlook windows. Note, you need to have a deep understanding of Windows API to move that way, see [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Also you may take a look at Add-in Express based form regions and views, see [How to add a custom header to your Outlook form or task pane: C# and VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/01/17/howto-display-your-own-header-for-an-advanced-outlook-region/) for more information.

Comment: I have no experience in Windows API using hooks but I guess this is not easy. Do you have some example on how to do it? Regarding Add-in Express I don't want to establish a dependency on third-parties and it is not free ;) I am trying to remove the title bar from the custom task pane, so as It can be done I was thinking on changing the color to be the same as my user control or even make background transparent. This is the reason of this post. Thanks for your support again.